# How to make html elements unselectable except textareas and inputs?

Tags: html, css

How to make elements unselectable but allow in to select textares and inputs?

I tried to play with css like -moz-user-select but didn't managed to get satisfactory result.

Answer (score 0):

As it says here: http://htmlcss.wikia.com/wiki/-moz-user-select, `-moz-user-select: none` should do the job.

Comment: did you mean -moz-user-select: text? I doesn't It allows to select any text on buttons as well.